# Relational database: Hierarchy of alternating models, where do foreign keys belong?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I need to make a recommendation questionnaire, where answering a bunch of questions would lead to some unique result; decisions along the way should affect the end result.

It's fine to make it very basic - so I have two models - `Questions` and `Answers`. Each question has two answers, and each of the answers leads to one other question - so graphing out the hieararchy ends up like sort of like a binary tree:

```
          Question 1
         /         \
    Answer 1      Answer 2
      /              \
 Question 2        Question 3
  /       \         /       \
Ans3     Ans4     Ans5     Ans6
...
```

So in plain english I'd say that each question `has many` answers, and each answer `has one` parent question and `has one` child question.

For a typical `has many` relationship, with the little experience I have I would probably just put the foreign key on the `many` end and not worry about the `one` end; so here `Answer` would get a `question_id` which doesn't have to be unique.

For `has_one` relationship, either end of relationship seems fine - but I already have a `question_id` on the answer; so maybe putting "parent" answer's `answer_id` on the question is appropriate, but that seems mighty confusing lexically - looking up something like `Question.answer` I would not intuitively understand it's the response that led to this question...

Alternatively, I could have two `question_ids` on in the `Answer` model - but then would have to differentiate between which one is "parent question" and which one is "follow-up question"...

Another consideration is that when I fetch the "next question" from the database (based on the answer), I also want to get the possible answers to display. Although optimizing the performance is not a requirement, it would be nice to "do it right" (or at least not completely wrong).

What's the best approach?

Comment: each question has multiple answers and each answer has one parent question and may have one (or no, if it's the end of the questionnaire) next question

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of help from my friends, found the right term for what I'm trying to save - it's a decision tree!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree

Then on this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278239/1592915 suggests using approach of a basically a man-to-many relationship between questions, where answers table is the intermediary.

Comment: You are interested in ternary relation(ship)/association "question Q with answer A leads to question R". Whether you can decompose it depends on what exactly "question" & "answer" mean. If Q & A are unique ids & in a *tree* then you can instead use projections "answer A answers question Q" & "answer A leads to question R". PS "Has" is useless as a name, it means "is related to" but doesn't describe *what* relationship. When we know what relationship, it is useful shorthand. A FK is an instance/edge in yet *another* (meta) relationship/dag per legal situations. Forget about them in design.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, really good point on the term "has" having very limited use!